# Batch command exit

Tags: batch-file, exit

I have to rewrite an old Batch file into Powershell script.

one line is

```
directory1\nunit-console.exe file1.dll /xml:results.xml


exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
```

I am a bit confused about the `"exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"` bit

Normally, just type in command line `>>exit` and enter. It will shut the screen.

What does  `%%ERRORLEVEL%%` bit mean?

thanks

Comment: Is there a line break prior to `exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%` that didn't make it into your post? Or is it all on one line?

Comment: there is a break point
the "exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%" is on a seperate line
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "DOS" shells (i.e. COMMAND.COM, CMD.EXE), variables are defined as `%VAR%`. `%ERRORLEVEL%` represents the return value of the last-executed command; it is like `$?` in Bash or Perl.

In this case, `exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%` appears to be an attempt to exit the batch script with the return value from the call to `nunit-console.exe`. (This script looks quite old, as both `exit` and the need for double-percent symbols has changed slightly between MS-DOS and the later shells in Windows 2000 and later.)

See [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php) for a discussion of how `exit` is used in the various shell versions.

[This MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75634) talks about using the % character in batch files. It was written for MS-DOS, but most of the same principles apply to later shells.

Comment: thanks!!! that is very helpfull.

I have another question. I know the result will be
either 
exit 0
or
exit _any-positive-number_ eg exit 23
Would it make any difference between exit 0 and exit 23?
thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "any difference?"

Comment: what I mean is.
I tried on cmd just now exit 0 and exit 23 will do the same thing-shut the dos screen down.
Is there any difference when I type exit 0 and exit 23 beside shutting down the dos screen.
thanks!

Comment: In earlier versions of COMMAND.COM (i.e. MS-DOS v3-6.x), `exit` would not close the shell if it was executed from a batch script. Without seeing the rest of the script, I assume that it was simply returning to the shell with the return code from `nunit-console.exe`. If you're rewriting the script in Powershell, you'll want to save the return code and use it as the script's exit code.